# Custom Form not showing

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I've designed a Windows Form in C#.NET using the visual editor. I want to call this form from another form. But the form is not detected from another form. The designed from is called **DataList** and the main code is as follows-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataList
{
    public partial class DataList : Form
    {
        //code, functions etc.
    }
}
```

When I call it from another form using `DataList.Show();` it highlights *DataList* with the error - *The name DataList does not exist in the current context.*

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can we see the code from where that form is called? My guess would be a different namespace...

Comment: Not distinguishing between types and objects is a vb.net programmer's affliction.  C# won't permit it.

Comment: Yes its a different Namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataList` is a class in which you can't call any non-static functions/methods directly.

You need to create an instance of it.

```
(new DataList()).Show();
```

Or probably

```
DataList myDataList;
myDataList = new DataList();
myDataList.Show();

// Do whatever you want?
```

If, in case, it *still* fails, then that *is* the namespace issue.

Comment: Following your advice it gives me now-The type or namespace name 'DataList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SamikSengupta That's what they say, namespace issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I fixed it by relocating all forms under one common namespace instead of different ones. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use NameSpace Name and Class Name SAME.

Go with this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use static for the class then you can run class.show();

Comment: Can you make a class static if it inherits a non-static class?

Comment: you should derived it from a object to inherit a non static class to static class.